# Keyboard hides edittext in expandablelistview child view in from second click on the same edittext onwards

Tags: android, keyboard, expandablelistview

When I click on EditText inside Children group of ExpandableListView, keyboard appears and edittext will move to above the keyboard and if I type on it EditText is updating also, but if i again click on the same Edittext after that the keyboard appears and which hides the edittext but if I type on it EditText is updating also.If i click on some other EditText and then back to the first EditText then there is no issues.The problem occurs only when i repeating the click on the same EditText after keyboard hides.Why this like so.I want to move the edittext above the keyboard each time i click on it.I have make the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the AndroidManifest.xml file.But it only allow for the first time only.Below is the xml for the edittext inside the expandable listview

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtRFAmount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
```

and for the ExpandableList view I used the below xml

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lstExpnAccounts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white" />
```

Please help to get me out of here.